# Why is there no "awaitTermination(Date deadline)" method?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a list of tasks submitted to an `ExecutorService`. But I need to shutdown the ExecutorService before a deadline of 2:30AM, even if the tasks are not finished. How can I achieve this? I checked the API, there is only a method like below:

```java
ExecutorService exec = //...    
exec.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But how can I make the following block executing atomically?  That is, how can I avoid the gap?  For example:

```
long timeDiff= calculate(now, deadline);
// Gap: assuming current thread does not have chance to run for 10 minutes...
exec.awaitTermination(timeDiff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't mean 'atomically', I think you mean 'without delay' here. So that `timeDiff` is still correct when calling `exec.awaitTermination()`.

I assume that's correct, so the answer is: *you can't*.

If you're interested in the details:
Your Java Code gets translated to Java Bytecodes and these get executed by the JVM which is a regular process running on your operating system. And you simply can't stop the operating system from interrupting threads (I assume you use a operating system with preemptive multitasking (every UNIX (including Linux and Mac OS X), Windows 95 or better, ...)).

Even if you could do all that in one Java Bytecode it would still not work as you want it to because the operating system could interrupt you in the middle of one Java Bytecode.

And even a `awaitTermination(Date deadline)` method wouldn't help here. It has to be implemented by someone, too.

The best you can do is to do it in as few bytecodes as possible.

If I were you, I'd probably do just as your code does it.

However, that *could* be a bit more precise:

```
Date deadline = ....;

final TimerTask stopTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }
};

new Timer().schedule(stopTask, deadline);
```

But as I said: There is no real guarantee `shotdownNow()` gets executed IMMEDIATELY at `deadline`. In reality, setting `deadline` to one second before the real deadline should be okay :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wait deadline in another high priority thread (or timer) and call `exec.shutdownNow()`